Confused about how eof-object? works when applying read-line to input data from (current-input-port) in (MIT) scheme
I'm using the MacOS port of MIT Scheme 12.1. I was trying to generalize a code pattern (I've used a lot) that reads a text file's contents to read instead from the standard in.
I think there's something subtle going on about the interactions between the console input and the (eof-object?) check that I don't understand.
Here's a small repro that makes my confusion plain ...
;; 
;;   Put this code block into a file named ./rw_io.scm.
;;
;;   Then comment out the appropriate (in_port ...) line associated with the Case you 
;;   want to look at.
;;
;;   Then run this script from the console using the line corresponding to the Case.
;;
;;   Usage: 
;;
;;     Case 1: scheme --batch-mode --load "./rw_io.scm"  --eval '(exit 1)'
;;
;;     Case 2: cat /tmp/L.txt | scheme --batch-mode --load "./rw_io.scm" --eval '(exit 1)'
;;
;;  /tmp/L.txt is just:
;;  % cat /tmp/L.txt
;;  foo
;;  bar
;;  mug
;;  wump
;;
(display "Start ...\n")
;;
;;  Show the state returned by the (do ...) look that reads the input one line at a time.
(display (string-append "Outer: "
(let
  (   
;;
;; Case 1:  - Read input from file.
    (in_port (open-input-file "/tmp/L.txt"))
;;
;; Case 2:  - Read input from current-input-port, which is console.
;;    (in_port (current-input-port))
    (long_str "")
  ) 
;;  
;;  loop over input begins here ...
  (do 
    ( 
;;    variable     init                         step
      (input_str   (read-line in_port)          (read-line in_port))
      (line_cnt    1                            (+ line_cnt 1))
    )
    (
;;  
;;  test - at end of file? Show the state and then return it.
      (eof-object? input_str) 
      (display (string-append "Inner: \n" long_str "\n"))
      long_str
    )
    (display (string-append "Line#: " (string line_cnt) ", string = " input_str "\n"))
    (set! long_str (string-append long_str "\t{ Line #: " (string line_cnt) ", string = " input_str " }\n"))
  )
)
))
;;
(display "Done ...\n")
;;
;;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

When applying Case 1 (setting in_port to the file) works exactly as I would expect.
% scheme --batch-mode --load "./rw_io.scm"  --eval '(exit 1)'

Start ...
Line#: 1, string = foo
Line#: 2, string = bar
Line#: 3, string = mug
Line#: 4, string = wump
Inner: 
    { Line #: 1, string = foo }
    { Line #: 2, string = bar }
    { Line #: 3, string = mug }
    { Line #: 4, string = wump }

Outer:  { Line #: 1, string = foo }
    { Line #: 2, string = bar }
    { Line #: 3, string = mug }
    { Line #: 4, string = wump }
Done ...
%

But Case 2 (setting in_port to use stdin from the console) ... reads everything fine, but comes unglued once the stdin stream is done.
% cat /tmp/L.txt | scheme --batch-mode --load "./rw_io.scm" --eval '(exit 1)'
Start ...
Line#: 1, string = foo
Line#: 2, string = bar
Line#: 3, string = mug
Line#: 4, string = wump
%

Clearly I don't understand what's going on with the interaction between the console-i/o, the (eof-object?) check, and how I am invoking scheme.

You're never reading from the console. In your second example, you're reading from a pipe.

I suspect it has something to do with when --eval '(exit 1)' gets executed. This is an implementation-specific feature, not part of the language.

Sorry. You're right. I am reading from a pipe, or stdin. In MIT Scheme this is called console-i/o-port. And I thought it had to do with the --eval '(exit 1)' also, but when I try cat /tmp/L.txt | scheme --batch-mode --load "./rw_io.scm" I get exactly the same result. I also suspect it's implementation dependent ... might even be implementation-on-MacOS issue.

@Barmar The issue isn't with (exit 1), it's with getting an end of file condition when reading from standard input. MIT Scheme is strange when that happens.

MIT Scheme exits when it gets an EOF trying to read from the process's standard input, even when it happens in a regular I/O function like read-line, not just in the Read part of the REPL. There's also strange differences between using --load and --eval of code that reads from standard input. Some examples:
$ cat input.scm
(display "Before\n")
(define x (read-line))
(display "Read: ")
(write x)
(newline)
(exit)
$ mit-scheme --batch-mode --load input.scm <<<"foo"
Before
Read: "foo"
$ mit-scheme --batch-mode --load input.scm </dev/null
Before
$ mit-scheme --batch-mode --eval "$(< input.scm)" <<<"foo"
Before
;Unbound variable: foo
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 3) => Specify a value to use instead of foo.
; (RESTART 2) => Define foo to a given value.
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.

2 error>
End of input stream reached.
$ mit-scheme --batch-mode --eval "$(< input.scm)" </dev/null
Before

(It's more obvious without --batch-mode:
$ mit-scheme --load input.scm </dev/null
MIT/GNU Scheme running under GNU/Linux
Type `^C' (control-C) followed by `H' to obtain information about interrupts.

Copyright (C) 2020 Massachusetts Institute of Technology
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Image saved on Sunday March 7, 2021 at 3:24:56 PM
  Release 11.2 || SF || LIAR/x86-64
;Loading "input.scm"...Before
End of input stream reached.
;... aborted

Post proelium, praemium.

)
In particular, the combination of --eval with input supplied on standard input is really odd. It looks like it's reading but not evaluating the input into the REPL, then partially evaluating the argument to --eval until the read-line causes an EOF, and then evaluating the previously read input instead of aborting. I don't understand that behavior at all.
Compare with Chicken Scheme:
$ csi -R 'chicken.io' -s input.scm <<<"foo"
Before
Read: "foo"
$ csi -R 'chicken.io' -s input.scm </dev/null
Before
Read: #!eof
$ csi -R 'chicken.io' -e "$(< input.scm)" <<<"foo"
Before
Read: "foo"
$ csi -R 'chicken.io' -e "$(< input.scm)" </dev/null
Before
Read: #!eof

which is more in line with what I'd expect.
You don't run into issues with your first go, which reads from a file port, because the special behavior about reading an EOF from standard input is never triggered -- it never tries to read from stdin at all. The second version, using (current-input-port), does, of course, set it off. I couldn't find this behavior documented in the manual, much less how to disable it. Because of this, MIT Scheme looks like a poor fit for writing traditional scripts in; it seems to be more intended for interactive use.

As an aside, your unconventional formatting and snake_case instead of kebab-case variables makes your code harder to read than it should be. Stick with decades of established Lispy language code style. Other people who have to read or work with your code will thank you.

(I used an older version, but 12 shows the same behaviors)

Also TIL that MIT Scheme's string accepts non-character arguments. I'd use format instead of those string-append's and that feature, though.

Regarding your explanation: Thanks! That MIT Scheme exits on EOF from stdin explains everything.  Seems my dream of using MIT scheme instead of Perl is not going to work. Oh well. Regarding my coding: Yeah - my repro was done too quickly and with feelings of frustration. (map (lambda ( x ) (display "I will remember to use pretty-print\n")) (seq 10))

@PaulBrown plenty of other scheme implementations out there to use instead. Though perl's a fine option too.
